# Can two non-equivalent polytopes of same dimension have the same graph?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

By a polytope I mean the convex hull of finitely many points. The graph of a polytope is the graph isomorphic to its 1-skeleton. By equivalence of polytopes I mean combinatorial equivalence, i.e. their face lattices are isomorphic.

I know that two polytopes can have isomorphic graphs while being non-equivalent, e.g. neighborly polytopes. However, all examples I know of are polytopes of different dimension. So I wonder:

> **Question:** Can there be two non-equivalent polytopes of the same dimension with the same graph?

Especially, are all $k$-neighborly polytopes of the same dimension equivalent?

Comment: For $k=\lfloor d/2\rfloor$ your question is also answered on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborly_polytope

Comment: In 3 dimensions, the 1-skeleton determines the combinatorial type. https://mathoverflow.net/a/308455/1345

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many non-equivalent neighborly polytopes, already in dimension $d=4$. See for example

- [Arnau Padrol. *"Many Neighborly Polytopes and Oriented Matroids"*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-013-9544-7)

Answer (score 7):

The 1-skeleton is usually not enough to recover the face lattice,
but under some conditions it is.
I did a quick google search, and read the [abstract in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.08739.pdf).

Comment: I knew the paper but I failed to remember it and to draw the conclusion from the abstract. Thank you.